# wp7 sending location Information multiple classes

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have multiple pages application and I want to send an information to my Database. Whatever the page is I want to send an information(current location of the user) according to my time period. Is there something like  a class or a method which works independently from the project. I mean whatever the page is or the current class is it continues working? I dont want to call this process when changing the page?

Thanks. Sorry for my verdancy. I couldnt think how to search.

Comment: I tried it. I put my in Application_Activated which I thought it application should check it while its running. But it never enters Application_Activated Method.

Comment: Application_Activated is call when the app is brought to foreground, for example, press Start button and the go back. In your case you should declare a global object exposed as property in App.xaml.cs in order to be accessed from everywhere in your app. Then if    you declare a Property -> public MyObjectPosition MyPosition { get; set; } you will be able to write/read it just coding: App.MyObjectPosition from any page.xaml in your project. If you want to initialize such property do it inside Application_Launching method instead of Application_Activated one.

Comment: The problem is not reaching the property from everywhere. I can call the method wherever it i but it is not logical. In any case I want to write it once !! and never look back again no search in other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a global object from the application object or use a static singleton.